# SQLDeveloper getting java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

[image]I just unzipped the sql developer 20.2.0. after opening the application and importing all the previous configurations. when i double click on 1 of the database connection to get connect

i have also setup the instantclient correctly and tested successfully.

the jdbc in this sql developer is using ojdbc8, provided by default in the downloaded sql developer zip file.

please assist how to overcome this issue to get connected to the dbs.

```
> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
at oracle.security.o3logon.a.a(Unknown Source)
at oracle.security.o3logon.b.g(Unknown Source)
at oracle.security.o3logon.O3LoginClientHelper.getEPasswd(Unknown Source)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:1238)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:1025)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:747)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:793)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:57)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:747)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:562)
at oracle.dbtools.connections.db.AbstractConnectionCreator.getConnection(AbstractConnectionCreator.java:174)
at oracle.dbtools.raptor.standalone.connection.RaptorConnectionCreator.getConnectionImpl(RaptorConnectionCreator.java:400)
at oracle.dbtools.raptor.standalone.connection.RaptorConnectionCreator.getConnection(RaptorConnectionCreator.java:119)
at oracle.dbtools.raptor.dialogs.conn.ConnectionPrompt$DefaultPrompter.promptForPassword(ConnectionPrompt.java:154)
at oracle.dbtools.connections.db.PasswordPrompter.promptForPassword(PasswordPrompter.java:15)
at oracle.dbtools.raptor.dialogs.conn.ConnectionPrompt.promptForPassword(ConnectionPrompt.java:202)
at oracle.dbtools.connections.db.DatabaseProvider.getConnection(DatabaseProvider.java:354)
at oracle.dbtools.connections.db.DatabaseProvider.getConnection(DatabaseProvider.java:337)
at oracle.jdevimpl.db.adapter.CAConnectionCreator.createConnectionImpl(CAConnectionCreator.java:52)
at oracle.javatools.db.DatabaseFactory.createConnection(DatabaseFactory.java:838)
at oracle.javatools.db.DatabaseFactory.createDatabase(DatabaseFactory.java:282)
at oracle.jdeveloper.db.DatabaseConnections.getDatabase(DatabaseConnections.java:656)
at oracle.dbtools.raptor.utils.Connections$ConnectionInfo.getDatabase(Connections.java:284)
at oracle.dbtools.raptor.utils.Connections.getConnection(Connections.java:1180)
at oracle.dbtools.raptor.utils.Connections.getConnection(Connections.java:1166)
at oracle.dbtools.raptor.navigator.db.DatabaseConnection.openConnectionImpl(DatabaseConnection.java:83)
at oracle.dbtools.raptor.navigator.db.DatabaseConnection.openConnectionImpl(DatabaseConnection.java:38)
at oracle.dbtools.raptor.navigator.db.BaseConnectionNode.getConnection(BaseConnectionNode.java:91)
at oracle.dbtools.raptor.navigator.db.impl.DatabaseTreeNode.getObjectFactory(DatabaseTreeNode.java:90)
at oracle.dbtools.raptor.navigator.db.impl.DatabaseTreeNode$LoadTask.doWork(DatabaseTreeNode.java:145)
at oracle.dbtools.raptor.navigator.db.impl.DatabaseTreeNode$LoadTask.doWork(DatabaseTreeNode.java:119)
at oracle.dbtools.raptor.backgroundTask.RaptorTask.call(RaptorTask.java:199)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at oracle.dbtools.raptor.backgroundTask.RaptorTaskManager$RaptorFutureTask.run(RaptorTaskManager.java:702)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
... 39 more

Answer (score 2):

just managed to fix this. its all about the sql developer version versus the java sdk that is installed on the laptop ... i have downgraded the sql developer to version 19.1 and its working fine with java 8.

Comment: no....you can run sqldev 20.2 with java 8 or java 11, no problems. there is something else going on with your 20.2 setup

Comment: @thatjeffsmith Any thoughts on what could be wrong with the setup? I'm getting this issue after unzipping SQLDeveloper 20.4.1.407 and importing my connections.

Comment: Reverting to v19 fixed the issue for me as well.

Comment: 20.4.1 needs a 21c client if you're using an Oracle home or instant client